# Using Requests and Beautifulsoup on Instagram

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, instagram

I was just making a simple Python program that would update me about my Instagram likes and followers. I don't want to open the browser every time it runs so I'm using requests and Beautifulsoup to get the page data. But the `get` method gives me a script that is totally different from the actual page script(the script in the browser). There's no **class** so I can't use `BeautifulSoup.find()` method on it. It seems like I'm receiving a different script because it's a robot accessing the page.

**Is there any other module or method I can use?**

Comment: Please show your working and sample page you need to scrap with desired output. BeautifulSoup `find` accepts any filter not only class.

Comment: @InfinityTM pay attention for your format :)

Comment: Try using Instagram API. It is documented  [Here](https://instagram.com/developer)